# Is Bootstrap 2 and Bootstrap 3 possible at the same time?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, joomla3.0, twitter-bootstrap-2

Is it possible to use a kind of no-conflict (like in jQuery) with two versions of the Bootstrap (2.x and 3.x) on a page?

The question has arisen because of the lack of compatibility of the Joomla 3.6! with the Bootstrap 3.x and intensive usage of the Bootstrap 2.3.2

There is idea to use customized, namespaced version of Bootstrap 3.x. But is that idea viable?

Note: there is [solution](http://www.readybytes.net/blog/item/upgrading-your-joomla-site-from-bootstrap-v2x-to-v3x.html) with template overrides. But it uses a lot of files for overriding and I have to use all of them for each of my 6+ templates

Comment: The solution of template overrides is going to be the best solution.